# R pivot_longer combining several columns

Tags: r, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe where several columns have similar information that I'd like to collapse into fewer columns. This seemed a little different from the normal uses of pivot_long or gather and I am stuck. My first thought was to make 3 separate sets and row-bind.. but I think someone here will have a more elegant solution!

```r
df<-data.frame("PicID"=letters[1:8],
"Near_Species1" = c("bird","bird", "bird", "dog", "dog", "human", "none", "human"),
"Count1" = c(1,1,1,1,2,1,0,1),
"Near_Species2" = c(NA,"human", NA, NA, "human", NA, NA, NA), 
"Count2" = c(NA,1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
"Far_Species"=c(NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, "bird"))
```

I'd like to pivot this longer with the basic structure of

```
PicID   NearorFar   Species   Count
```

I'd like to have at least 1 row per picture based on Near_Species1, regardless of what is there (none, NA, etc).

And if there are any species other than "none" in Near_Species2, Count2 OR Far_Species, I'd like another row. Essentially a "none" for species is an NA. But I'd like at least 1 row to keep track of that ID.

output would look like this, but remove rows where species is an NA.

```r
df_out <- data.frame(
  "PicID" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
          "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
          "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"),
"NearorFar"=rep(c("Near", "Far"),times=c(16, 8)),
"Species"= paste(c("bird","bird", "bird", "dog", "dog", "human", "none", "human", 
                NA,"human", NA, NA, "human", NA, NA, NA, 
                NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, "bird")),
"Count"= c(1,1,1,1,2,1,0,1,
          NA,1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
          rep(NA, 8))
)
```

Comment: Do you need `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = matches('Species'), names_to = 'NearorFar', values_to = 'Species') %>% mutate(NearorFar = str_remove(NearorFar, "_.*")) %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Count'), names_to = NULL, values_to = 'Count', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% distinct`

Comment: let me try quick, I realized this is easier if I change "none" to NAs for NearSpecies2 and FarSpecies (easier to groom out at the end).

Comment: Yes, the "none" changed to NA will be picked up in `values_drop_na`

Comment: That works! I found  that "names_to = Null" gave me the error: "Error: The LHS of `:=` must be a string or a symbol" .   however, if I just gave it a name and deleted it later, that worked fine. 
THANK YOU so much! I was hung up on this all afternoon!!!

Comment: The `names_to=NULL` is from the newer version of tidyr

Comment: aha, will update. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = matches('Species'), names_to = 'NearorFar', 
         values_to = 'Species') %>% 
  mutate(NearorFar = str_remove(NearorFar, "_.*")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Count'), names_to = NULL, 
          values_to = 'Count', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  distinct
```